# How can I update a Pandas column safely (after some manipulation) if one row's value is formatted incorrectly?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I am essentially trying to take data in the `Date` column in my dataframe, and subtract it from the date today in order to get the timedelta (which I will be storing in a new column). The issue I am running into is that i the `Date` value is formatted incorrectly or not a date at all, that will either cause my program to crash, or when I try to handle that error with simply mess up the other row's data. Here is my code:

```
def add_delta_to_dataframe():
    df = create_messages_dataframe()

    date = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format='%m/%d/%Y', errors="ignore")
    now = datetime.datetime.today()
    try:
        delta = ((date - now).dt.days) + 1
        df['Delta'] = delta
    except TypeError:
        pass

    return df
```

I have also tried to iterate through:

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format='%m/%d/%Y', errors="ignore")
now = datetime.datetime.today()
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    try:
        delta = ((row['Date'] - now).days) + 1
        df['Delta'] = delta
    except TypeError:
        continue
```

But no luck here either. Any ideas on doing this would be greatly appreciated. I either get an error if I don't catch the error, or the output leaves all `Delta` values as `NaN`. My expected output would be the columns with the correct date format to have the `Delta` value there, and the others to be `NaN`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIUC, you can leverage the `errors='coerce'` argument of `pd.to_datetime`, which will set unformattable strings to `NaT`. Take the following `df` for an example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'date':['1999-01-01', 'xyz', '2000-05-05']})

>>> df
         date
0  1999-01-01
1         xyz
2  2000-05-05
```

You can create your `timedelta`-like column using:

```
df['my_timedelta'] = pd.to_datetime('today') - pd.to_datetime(df['date'], errors='coerce')
```

Which results in:

```
>>> df
         date my_timedelta
0  1999-01-01    7066 days
1         xyz          NaT
2  2000-05-05    6576 days
```

Comment: In my opinion this is exactly what OP need :)

Comment: Thanks so much, this does seem to do it! Is there any reason this my `Date` format to: `2018-04-29` instead of the `'%m/%d/%Y'` I have specified?

Comment: Glad I could help! You can still specify whichever date format makes sense with your data in your call to `pd.to_datetime`. Anything that can't be parsed in that format will be set to `NaT`

Comment: Got it working, had the format specified in the wrong place. Thanks again!